# How to use awk to reformat a set of data?

Tags: sorting, awk, multiple-columns, reformatting

I have a large set of traveltime data for earthquakes formatted in 4 columns like so:

```
     0.000     1.000     0.000         0
     0.050     0.044     0.010         1
     0.100     0.075     0.010         1
     0.150     0.108     0.010         1
     0.200     0.117     0.010         1
     0.250     0.160     0.010         1
     0.300     0.197     0.010         1
```

I need to use awk to reformat this into a different format that has 6 columns like so:

```
3
s 1 2.9901 38
r 3 0 0 2.27046 0.01
r 5 0 0 2.53864 0.01
r 7 0 0 2.66227 0.01
r 9 0 0 2.82365 0.01
r 11 0 0 3.23862 0.01
r 13 0 0 3.52581 0.01
r 15 0 0 4.15172 0.01
```

The key being that the original set is structured as [x position, traveltime, error, flag] and i need it to become [r, x position, z position (0), flag, traveltime, error]. I'm very new to using awk and I'm wondering if there is a way to complete this in a single script, or if it has to be done piece-wise.

What I've tried with my limited experience with awk was this:

```
{
printf "%s %d %d %d %f %f \n" , $1=r, $2=$1, $3=0, $4=0, $5=$2, $6=$3;
}
```

So far this has simply output a series of columns of zeros with the column of r's missing entirely.

EDIT:
To clarify, the 2 examples are drawn from 2 different data sets just to show the formats. The original data is already in text file form and I need to change it to fit the format of the second example. This includes adding columns.

Comment: how do you generate the 2nd line - `s 1 2.9901 38` - or is that a set of hard-coded values and has nothing to do with the values in the original file?

Comment: Yes, this is quite unclear. @Dustin, please edit your post to clarify

Comment: your sample input and expected output do not appear to match, eg, how do you get from (1st input row) `traveltime = 1.000` to (3rd output row) `traveltime = 2.27046`? if you're not doing any sort of calculations, and you're just copying data from input to output, then please update the question to insure the sample input and expected output actually match

Comment: consider reviewing [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then come back and update the question accordingly

Comment: how does x position in the input get transformed to x position in the output? For example, you have `0.000` becoming `3` and `0.200` becoming `11`

Comment: *"i need it to become [r, x position, z position (0), flag, traveltime, error]."* ... If that is correct, you're just adding an `r` as the first field, and a `0` as the third, so `awk '{print "r",$1,0,$2,$3,$4}' file` may help you. The `,` char will expand to whatever you set for `FS=` , where the space char is the default value for `FS`. Good luck.

Comment: Regarding "the 2 examples are drawn from 2 different data sets" - you only have 1 example in your question and that example is comprised of sample input and expected output. What you're saying is that the expected output you've shown is the output you expect from some other set of data than the sample input you've shown us. That makes your question hard to understand and impossible to test a potential solution with so don't do that - show the output you expect from the input you provide, not the output you expect from some other set of data that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
printf "%s %d %d %d %f %f \n" , $1=r, $2=$1, $3=0, $4=0, $5=$2, $6=$3;
}
```

This is not how one is supposed to use GNU `AWK`'s [`printf` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html), compare it with example from User Guide

```
awk '{ printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, $2 }' mail-list
```

Observe that you simply state which field you want and do not make any assignment (`=`), after repairing that and using string literal denoting `r` rather than variable named `r` for `file.txt` holding

```
 0.000     1.000     0.000         0
 0.050     0.044     0.010         1
 0.100     0.075     0.010         1
 0.150     0.108     0.010         1
 0.200     0.117     0.010         1
 0.250     0.160     0.010         1
 0.300     0.197     0.010         1
```

command

```
awk '{printf "%s %d %d %d %f %f \n" , "r", $1, 0, 0, $2, $3}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
r 0 0 0 1.000000 0.000000 
r 0 0 0 0.044000 0.010000 
r 0 0 0 0.075000 0.010000 
r 0 0 0 0.108000 0.010000 
r 0 0 0 0.117000 0.010000 
r 0 0 0 0.160000 0.010000 
r 0 0 0 0.197000 0.010000
```

as you might observe this is not desired output, as this is not compliant with requirement stipulating going from [x position, traveltime, error, flag] to [r, x position, z position (0), flag, traveltime, error]. This could be done by changing order and using right format codes for each column.

```
awk '{printf "%s %f %f %d %f %f \n", "r", $1, 0, $4, $2, $3}' file.txt
```

and output is now

```
r 0.000000 0.000000 0 1.000000 0.000000 
r 0.050000 0.000000 1 0.044000 0.010000 
r 0.100000 0.000000 1 0.075000 0.010000 
r 0.150000 0.000000 1 0.108000 0.010000 
r 0.200000 0.000000 1 0.117000 0.010000 
r 0.250000 0.000000 1 0.160000 0.010000 
r 0.300000 0.000000 1 0.197000 0.010000
```

Observe that `%f` cause certain number of digits after `.`, if you need another number of digits for certain column use e.g. `%.03f` to get 3 digits after `.`

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*